# Get ID Element from another HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I haven't found a solution in the Internet yet and I searched for hours...

I would like to read another HTML File with AngularJS, that I can use some elements from this site in my own Homepage.

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to fetch content from remote site the on the success callback you can convert the returned response to a document using `DomParser`

```
 $http.get('<link to remote site>').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

  var parser = new DOMParser();

  var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

  var element = doc.getElementById('id');

}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  //handle $http error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

without more information everything i can say is:

AngularJS works with so called "Services" to solve your Problem. I always create a factory, which factores my needed Object and a service, which calls that factory.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

angular is a template management enginge...so you always get your HTML codes from defined templates

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates

greetings

Comment: and what do you want to tell me / us with this saying? that you do not have any problems anymore? bro really, thats all i can say with that few information u gave us